# Securing 'secret' key in AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, security

Let's say I'm fetching data from an `API` using `AJAX` calls. *(e.g. themoviedb)*

Now the `API` requires an `API` key to be able to get data from but I don't want to show this `API` key to the public in case of abusing this key.

Is there a solution to make sure this key is secured/hidden instead of routing through a PHP function?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + data + "&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        data: data,
    },

    success: function (resData) {
        // whatever functions here
    }
})
```

Comment: The client will be able to see anything you pass over the wire and it will be accessible to anyone who knows where to look as plain text. If this needs to be kept secret then you will need to encapsulate the api calls in another level of abstraction on your secure server.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. It's completely impossible.

Instead of distributing your secret keys to the client, store the key server-side and "proxy" the resource by exposing your own API that can make the 3rd party request for the client.

Your own API can use whatever form of throttling and authentication you wish.